# Can we make our own S-Boxes, IP, IP~, And other tables in DES? Will it Still Work or should be use what they've provided?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, des

I'm trying to construct a DES implementation of my own!
But i'm not successful with the implementation

I use All the tables like Initail permutation, Expansion Permutation table, Permutation function table, PC-1, PC-2 and all the s-boxes of my own random bit positions .

Should we use the S-Boxes provided by DES or we can create on our own??

Comment: In what way are you not successful?

Answer (score 5):

The first rule of cryptography: *never ever invent anything yourself!* Unless you have a PhD and years of experience, you *will* end up creating gaping security holes. As a matter of fact, history shows that even people *with* a PhD and years of experience often make security mistakes. Sure, you can do it for fun and educational experience, but please do not ever consider putting anything of it into production. Sorry for being so negative, but this is the reality (and, for the record, I am also a person who should never ever invent anything cryptography-related myself).

When it comes to *implementation* of something invented by a true security expert (and generally accepted as being secure), there are still many traps to walk into, in particular side-channel attacks. But again, implementing it for fun and learning is of course a good thing.

When it comes to DES specifically, the contents of the S-boxes is a part of the algorithm itself and can *not* be changed without also losing compatibility with all other DES-encrypted data.

Comment: Ad "people with PhD and years of experience making mistakes": that's why peer review is so important in this area. Un-reviewed algorithms/implementations are often considered broken by default.

Comment: I'm doin this for my project work. i read _With the adoption of DES 20 years ago, many critics questioned the involvement 
of the NSA in generating the s-boxes. Some questioned if a back-door, or at the 
very least, a reduced capability open to cryptanalysis, was hidden in the boxes. 
This prompted several researchers to find alternate s-boxes that would be secure 
without worry of the NSA potentially cracking them. Since the creation of DES, 
plenty of research has gone into finding better s-boxes and better techniques to 
break them._  . So thought of trying new s-box....

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Very true; +1 for the "broken by default" formulation. Note to other readers (I suppose you are aware of it): "Proprietary" and "un-reviewed" is pretty much a synonym in this case; using proprietary encryption solutions is very risky.

Comment: @Hari: if you've got doubts about the quality of DES, then switch to a more modern alternative.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: True, but I seem to recall from my textbook (_Cryptography and Network Security_ by Stallings) that the suspicion of a government has pretty much ceased because no one has been able to pinpoint weaknesses in the S-boxes. But by all means, as long as you're just playing around, feel free to use other S-boxes; just be aware that then you won't be able to encrypt something with a standard DES implementation and decrypt it with yours.

Comment: @all: Thanks for your guidance, But i just asked can we create our own S-Boxes, and will it still encrypt and decrypt correctly or is there a relation between all the tables so that if changed they will bring wrong results???

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: I'm sitting in front of the same book , But making the S-Boxes dynamic for ever encryption will make cryptanalysis impossible for DES rite??

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: If by "correctly" you mean "encrypting the data D with the key K on my implementation should give the same output as encrypting D with K on another DES implementation", then the answer is no. Your implementation would give a different result if you change the S-boxes. If you mean "encrypting D with K on my implementation would give a result that can be decrypted with K on my implementation", then yes, I think so; the other steps in the algorithm don't depend on the specific S-box values, as far as I recall.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: Interesting idea, but again, in cryptography, ideas that seem good often aren't (and you won't find out until someone breaks your encryption). Since I am not an expert, I have no better arguments than that, I'm afraid. Random S-boxes (which would, in a sense, be an additional key, since the receiver would need to know them) would perhaps break existing analysis techniques, but any specific randomly-generated S-box risks exhibiting some weakness that will perhaps render it vulnerable to e.g. differential cryptanalysis (but I don't know anything about that, so I'm not certain).

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset : Only if you've a chosen set of plaintext and ciphertext you can crypt analyze , but as of my algorithm each time you encrypt all the boxes changes its nature so you've to create about 2**15 plain and ciphertext at the same millisecond, cuz my algorithm creates the boxes wrt to time... So its impossible to cryptanalyse. _(To be exact:enchanced cryptanalysis attack can break 9-round DES with 2**15.8 known plaintexts and has a 2**29.2 time complexity (Biham et al., 2002).from wikipedia)_.....

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: There are many ways to perform cryptanalysis. Some require a _chosen_ plaintext with the resulting encrypted ciphertext; some require a _chosen_ ciphertext with the resulting decrypted plaintext; some only require that you _know_ both the plaintext and the ciphertext; and, with weak ciphers (which will almost always be the result of attempts to "improve" existing algorithms) can even be broken _with the ciphertext only_.

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: U r completely rite. In my alogirthm the same plaintext with same key encrypted twice will result in different ciphertext. Finding the relation between the two different ciphertext which uses completely different tables and s-boxes make it much difficult to cryptanalyse just with the ciphertext.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: With these time-dependent S-boxes, how does the receiver of an encrypted message know how the S-boxes are supposed to vary, so that he can decrypt the message?

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset:A special key will be generated to regenerate s-boxes .                                                          special_key (xor) Userkey= Stored key in Database.......           So the user needs to provide his password , which will (xor) with stored password inn DB to get the special key for regenerating the s-boxes.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan There are perfectly valid ways to ensure the same plaintext does not encrypt to the same ciphertext - IVs. If randomly generated S-Boxes were a practical way to enhance a cipher's security, people would be doing it. Don't assume that you're smarter than the best educated cryptography researchers - none of us are.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: I see. Well, it will _work_ per se, but as @Nick Johnson said, if this was a security-enhancing idea, it would probably have been discovered and proven by someone else by now. Even if this trick makes the cipher more secure (which I strongly doubt), it is by no means unbreakable, since there is still a "connection" between the different S-boxes, that could perhaps be exploited by a skilled cryptanalyst.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: Also, if you are worried that repeated occurrences of the same plaintext will produce the same ciphertext, that _is_ indeed a valid concern. However, the correct solution is to use a suitable [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).

Comment: @Nick Johnson:I'm not smarter than the educated researchers, i agree, Let me be the dumbest person trying to do something stupid, I've my own pseudo Random generator and trying to work out something.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: I'm sorry if it seems that we're trying to make you feel dumb. Our point is just that almost _everyone_ on the planet, including us, are "dumb" when it comes to cryptography. The reason this is important is that someone who doesn't know it will probably make an expensive mistake one day by designing his/her own cipher and using it for something important; such a cipher will almost certainly be broken. It's excellent that you want to experiment and learn, and feel free to continue asking questions. Just don't have the attitude that your cipher is "impossible to cryptanalyse".

Comment: @Nick Johnson: I don't see the problem of _playing around_ with self-created ciphers for fun and learning, as long as the cipher isn't used for anything serious... I certainly was extremely excited the first time I wrote my first "encryption" program with a monoalphabetic substitution cipher. :-)

Comment: @Asamund Agreed - as long as it's just for learning purposes, which also means you have to have some way to discover what's wrong with your approach, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

DES without its original S-Boxes would likely be insecure. BTW NSA enhanced them making them more [resistant to differential cryptanalysis](http://news.cnet.com/Saluting-the-data-encryption-legacy/2010-1029_3-5381232.html), which was unknown to the civilian world at the time.

OTOH if you want user generated S-Boxes you could use the Russian cipher GOST 28147-89 (14.1 in Applied Cryptography) which uses user supplied S-Boxes.